# How to implement token based authentication for my API?

Tags: rest, api, security, authentication, hash

I have a Django backend which will be served as my API endpoints. Users are identified by `username` and `password` and have some extra information and should be able to consume my same API, so I want to grant tokens for them.

1. How to create API keys for them to use? (Would a uuid serve a good purpose here?)
2. How to generate tokens for them? (I could imagine that some way like `sha256(api_key + password + some_salt)`, where `salt` is some timestamp object would do the trick and also help in expiration)
3. How to generate a refresh token to be used for refreshing an expired token? (I have no idea here)

I took a look at Oauth 2.0 but TBH I could not figure it out completely and it is overly complicated as my API server will also be my authentication server.

Comment: i think it would be better if you first become familiar with JWt  authentication . if you agree I can help you right now.  just give the response.

Comment: @spider01 I know what JWT is already.

Comment: checkout my [github repo](https://github.com/naveenjain07/Django_custom_authentication) for hint about custom authentican system   in django.

Comment: @spider01 if you could just provide some high level mechanics as an answer for me and any possible future reader I would be grateful.

Comment: @RakshithRavi actually I was reinventing the wheel here; *Django Rest Framework* has a builtin token authentication and there's this third party [django-rest-knox](https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox) which is recommended in *DRF*s doc. Although for my project I ended up creating a custom token authentication which turned out not so different from the *DRF*s implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to build your own authentication scheme, nor deploy your own cryptographic functions. Nowadays the industry standard for API authentication and authorization is [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/), it provides all the requirements you've described in a robust but rather simple to implement solution.

If the mentioned application does not require any of the OAuth 2.0 authorization concepts, using [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) is certainly a great approach. OpenID Connect is a protocol built on top of OAuth 2.0:

> It allows Clients to verify the identity of the End-User based on the
>   authentication performed by an Authorization Server, as well as to
>   obtain basic profile information about the End-User in an
>   interoperable and REST-like manner.

API authentication technologies are widely available in different forms, even [SAML 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0) can be implemented for such scenarios (more infrastructure is required), anyhow for what you have described, OpenID Connect certainly cover all requirements.

Comment: I will not be building my own authentication scheme nor deploying my cryptographic functions as I know it's a terrible idea. But I want to use my own API server as my authentication server too, is it possible with Oauth? if so point me to some tutorial for implementing it

Comment: Using OAuth is for delegated authorization which is not necessary in this case, as the users access their own data.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to solve this is a classical Session-Cookie, [Django directly offers this functionality](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/).

If you do not want to hold state on the server side you may look into JSON Web Tokens.

Comment: REST APIs are stateless and don't use cookies! besides JWT does not answer my question for how to create API key and tokens!

Comment: If you create API keys that are only valid for some time, you must keep a state on the server side, how else would the server know whether the key is still valid.

Comment: In rest each request will carry the token so the server can authenticate it, but each request is independent from another and may even be sent from command line so it does not support session but it will eventually look like session.

Comment: But how does the server know whether the token is valid?
You could store a uuid on the server side and validate whether the uuid exists and what permissions are associated with this uuid. But if the way a user get's this token is by submitting username and password you have just reimplemented sessions. So why not use sessions in the first place.

Comment: By using token if it expires user will be able to issue another token providing its refresh token but it's not the case with sessions

Comment: Are we talking about machine to machine communication? Or is this a normal webapplication (or SPA) with an API in the backend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199638/discussion-between-masked-man-and-benjaminh).